# [HTML CSS JS]Prevent user from changing values using before element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to block three tables with inputs using before selector.
Via jquery i'm adding class disabled-element to every table:

```
$("table").toggleClass("disabled-element");
```

Here is my disabled-element in css:

```
.disabled-element::before {
  background-color: #4e555b;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  content: ""; 
}
```

table tructures:

```
<table class="table table-stripped">
<thead>
  <th scope="col">Rotor Number</th>
  <th scope="col">Current values</th>
</thead>
</table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td></td><td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

but it looks like the class is only added to  selector:
[image]

Comment: Have you added `table { position: relative; }`? Please provide an MVCE. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: for onlu table it's not working as i expected but now I added position: relative to thead and tbody selectors and it's working great. Thank you.Please add it as an answer, then I will be able to give you some points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed `position: relative` statement for parent element